# Angular 6 service call with a date parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular6, asp.net-core-2.0

My goal is to display on the front-end all of the results of a table, given the following parameters: an agency (ID), a startDate, and an endDate.

My C# back-end is doing most of the leg-work:

```
[HttpGet("~/api/agencies/{agency}/housewatches/")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllAsync(int agency, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null)
{

var housewatches = _context.HouseWatchMaster.Where(
    s => s.Agency.Equals(agency)
        && !s.Retired.Equals("Y"));

if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
    housewatches = housewatches.Where(
        s => (s.StartDate >= startDate && s.EndDate <= endDate)
            || (s.StartDate <= startDate && s.EndDate >= endDate)
            || (endDate >= s.StartDate && endDate <= s.EndDate)
            || (startDate >= s.StartDate && startDate <= s.EndDate));

return Ok(await housewatches
    .AsQueryable()
    .ToListAsync());
}
```

This is what I have for my service call so far:

```
// Get all house watches with the given agency, and optional start and end date
getHouseWatchesWithDates(
  agency: number | string,
  startDate?: Date,
  endDate?: Date
): Observable<HousewatchModel[]> {
return this.http
  .get<HousewatchModel[]>(
    `${this.apiUrl}/agencies/${agency}/housewatches`
  )
  .pipe(
    tap(houseWatches => console.log(`fetched house watches!`)),
    catchError(e => throwError(e))
  );
}
```

Any help on moving forward with including the startDate and endDate params in my service call would be greatly appreciated! Also, please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Steve For this particular query, instead of getting ALL the rows back from this table, I want to get the row(s) based off of a provided ID, and if they are still active. A table entry is considered active if today's date falls on or after the date in the "startDate" column, and if whatever date in the "endDate" column has not passed yet. I hope this helps!

Comment: are you using entity framework or raw query? And whats the table definition?

Comment: @Steve I am using EF Core. Regarding the table definition, what exactly would you like to know? The name of the table?

Comment: is agency ID within the same table? do you need to join any other table to get that column? is date nullable?

Comment: @Steve the agency ID is within the same table. I do not need to join any other table. The Dates are nullable.

Comment: in such case it should be simple as adding a condition in your where clause. && agencyID == agency

Comment: @Steve sorry, I initially posted an abbreviated version of my C# GetAll method. I have updated it to show my where clause.

Comment: A couple of strong recommendations on working with dates between your asp.net web server side / browser client side tiers. 1) Always pass dates back/forth using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting. 2) If working with time component, always pass the UTC value and convert to that value as early as possible in the call stack (conversely to local datetime as late as possible in the call stack).

Comment: @Igor whats wrong with storing datetime as datetime column in the DB?

Comment: @Steve - let me clarify. My comment is specific to how dates / date times are passed between the web server and the browser. I am not addressing how dates or datetimes are persisted as it seemed out of scope in the question and, judging from the EF lambda, they are already being persisted as the correct/native type.

Comment: You say "A table entry is considered active if today's date falls on or after the date in the "startDate" column, and if whatever date in the "endDate" column has not passed yet" then you should compare StartDate and EndDate with Today, something like this: s.StartDate <= today && S.EndDate > today. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with all the || in the lambda. If you would run your attempt as a SQL statement do you get the expected results?

Comment: @Iztoksson Yes, I have tested this C# method in multiple ways, and it works fine. My question isn't with the C# method. It's with writing the service call in my front-end.

Comment: @DavidD. - seeing as how both dates are optional you have a couple of choices. 1) Pass the values by query string. 2) Post the values in the Http message body and use either Post or Put instead of Get. 3) Make them non optional and a part of the Url, assign a default value where you want to ignore the incoming value later in the query or pass null explicitly. My personal preference would be number 1 (query string) because you can still use HttpGet.

Comment: I cannot see where you are passing the date arguments to the link that is passed to `http.get`. The best way would be to pass the date in ISO format as `yyyy-mm-dd` as query params.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is to make your C# date paramteres as `[FromQuery]`, eg:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllAsync(int agency, 
    [FromQuery(Name="startDate")] DateTime? startDate = null, 
    [FromQuery(Name="endDate")] DateTime? endDate = null)
```

In the Angular service check if they are not null or undefined and pass them as query params.

```
getHouseWatchesWithDates(
    agency: number | string,
    startDate?: Date,
    endDate?: Date
): Observable<HousewatchModel[]> {
    let link = `${this.apiUrl}/agencies/${agency}/housewatches`;
    let params = '';

    if (startDate) {
        params = 'startDate=' + startDate.toISOString() + '&'
    }

    if (endDate) {
        params += 'endDate=' + endDate.toISOString();
    }

    if (params) {
        link += `?${params}`;
    }

    return this.http
        .get<HousewatchModel[]>(link)
        .pipe(
            tap(houseWatches => console.log(`fetched house watches!`)),
            catchError(e => throwError(e))
        );
}
```

This should pass the parameters if any.

Comment: FYI : You don't need the `Name` parameters in the `[FromQuery]` attributes if you want them to be the same as the name of the function parameter.

Comment: You probably don't need it, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Husein Roncevic has already provided an excellent answer for you. However, I would like to introduce another way (probably a harder way) of doing this.
Considering your requirement, I believe you are not interested in the 'Time' segment of the DateTime object. If so, you can pass date, month and year as integer parameters. Please see the following code. This is a working example from my current project.

An advantage is; this method helps me to avoid DateTime format issues and culture incompatibilities.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Arrivals Report Seven Day Forecast
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="day"></param>
    /// <param name="month"></param>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("arrivalreportsevendayforecast/{day:int}/{month:int}/{year:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel>>> GetArrivalsReportSevenDayForecast(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        IList<ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel> arrivingStudents = await _applicationService.Value.GetArrivalsReportSevenDayForecast(selectedDate);
        return Ok(arrivingStudents);
    }
```

If you are keen to see the front-end as well, feel free to read the code below. This is how I normally pass a DateTime as a query parameter in Angular GET requests.

```
public getArrivalsReportSevenDayForecast(selectedDate1 : Date): Observable<ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel[]> {
const params = new HttpParams();
const day = selectedDate1.getDate();
const month = selectedDate1.getMonth() + 1 // Remember this increment
const year = selectedDate1.getFullYear();

const data = this.svcHttp.get<ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel[]>(this.routePrefix +
  `/arrivalreportsevendayforecast/${day}/${month}/${year}`, { params: params }).pipe(
  map<ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel[], ArrivalsReportSevenDayForecastModel[]>(arrivingList => {
    // do mapping here if needed       
    return arrivingList;
  }),
  catchError((err) => this.svcError.handleError(err)));

return data;
}
```